# prepareForSegue not working prior to iphone 5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a second view controller that passes a String to my first view controller.

I'm using:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {

    NSString *intro = @"Canceled";
    ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.cancelstring = intro;
}

//WHEN YOU HIT START BUTTON
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"start"]) {
  //get width
    NSString *width = _widthinput.text;
  }

...

 ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.widthstring = width;
```

My first view controller in the header file has:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString  *widthstring;
```

In my first ViewController.m I refer to

```
widthstring
```

by referencing to

```
_widthstring (auto generated by the system).
```

When running on iOS 9.3.4 this does NOT work on devices prior to the iPhone 5S. The data passes just fine when printing to the console _widthstring on all my devices iPhone 5S and newer.

What is the correct way to send segue data that works on ALL devices and why does this only work on iPhone 5S and newer despite the iOS version being the same?

Comment: Your property should be `copy` or `strong`, not `weak`.

Comment: @dan That fixed it. I can't believe I missed that. Why is it that it has a different behavior across devices?

Comment: It probably works on 64-bit devices because they use tagged pointers for small strings which changes how their memory is managed.  It probably wouldn't work on any device if you passed a string big enough that it didn't fit in a tagged pointer.